# Problema ao carregar conteudo de tag <span> no codebin

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Estou fazendo um javascript para jogar o resultado de uma consulta em uma tag , porém a consulta não é exibida na `tag`. Estou na mesma página e chamando a função pelo codebehide.

```
  function preenche_tit(tit_num_ptd, hea_end_ptd) { 
     self.opener.END.innerHTML = "&nbsp;&nbsp;" + trim(hea_end_ptd) + "&nbsp;" + trim(tit_num_ptd) + "&nbsp;";
    }

 <span class="form-control" id="END">&nbsp</span>
```

Comment: olha se runat=server na sua tag span funciona.

Comment: Não deu certo. estou fazendo assim:  document.getElementById('END').innerHTML =  ...
E retorna: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: Em que momento você está usando essa função JavaScript? Mova o script para o fim da tag body e teste.